# illegal string offset with while loop

Tags: php

```
<?php
include 'inc/connect.php';

if ($_GET['id'] )
        {
            $p_id = $_GET["id"];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE p_id= '$p_id'";
            //var_dump($query);
            $resu = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resu))
            { 
              ?> <img src="<?php echo $p_id['p_image']; ?>" alt="" /> <?php 
              //var_dump($query);                               
            }
        }

?>
```

this is my code and this is showing me error on my browser what can i do..?
image cant load

Comment: Start by posting the error.

Comment: this is code give me help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this

```
<img src="<?php echo $rs['p_image']; ?>" alt="" />
```

to

```
<img src="<?php echo $p_id['p_image']; ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: can you please explain why your code is working for OP??

Comment: i am making a ecommerce website
which is almost ready just making add to cart

Comment: this coding is for product deatils
it fet image from data base as a product detail